# Convert Intervals to DateTimes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, intervals

I have a DataFrame which contains intervals in which a certain sensor was active:

```
                 start                 end
0  2018-06-01 08:55:10 2018-06-01 09:01:00
1  2018-06-01 09:02:20 2018-06-01 09:04:55
2  2018-06-01 09:11:35 2018-06-01 09:23:44
```

I would like to do some time-series analysis on this data. To do so I want to convert this data to a proper time-series having timestamps every `X` minutes. Here an example with `X = 5` min:

```
                 time active
0 2018-06-01 08:55:10      1
1 2018-06-01 09:00:10      1
2 2018-06-01 09:05:10      0
3 2018-06-01 09:10:10      1
```

You can read the above as "`active == 1` if sensor was active within interval `[t, t+X]`".

Please note that the intervals are not always disjoint.

At the moment, I'm converting the intervals to `DatetimeIndex` with a frequency of `X` min. Afterwards I'm resampling the series again (accounts for overlapping intervals):

```
indices = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    indices.append(pd.date_range(row['start'], row['end'], freq='5T'))
index = indices[0].append(indices[1:])
series = pd.Series(np.ones(len(index), dtype=bool), index=index)
series = series.resample('5T').max().fillna(0)
```

My dataset as about 15m entries. The above takes quite a long time to run. I would like to do this more performant.

Does anyone has a good idea?

Comment: I think you'll get better support from the Stack Overflow community if you post a coding attempt, and then ask how you can make it (a) correct or (b) vectorized.

Comment: Are all intervals disjoint?

Comment: I added a code snippet of what I'm doing right now. Unfortunately, my intervals are not disjoint.

Comment: What happens if there are two or more sensors active at the same time? Should active be still 1?

Comment: @klaus exactly, for overlapping intervals `active` is still 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intervals are disjoint and the rows are sorted (assuming one single sensor and sequential data), like in your example, you can do a simple loop and check row by row.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create your dataframe
x = np.array([
    ['2018-06-01 08:55:10', '2018-06-01 09:01:00'],
    ['2018-06-01 09:02:20', '2018-06-01 09:04:55'],
    ['2018-06-01 09:11:35', '2018-06-01 09:23:44']
    ])

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['start', 'end'])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
print(df)
```

Dataframe:

```
     start                 end
0 2018-06-01 08:55:10 2018-06-01 09:01:00
1 2018-06-01 09:02:20 2018-06-01 09:04:55
2 2018-06-01 09:11:35 2018-06-01 09:23:44
```

Code to generate results:

```
results = []
interval = pd.Timedelta('5 minutes') # interval X
start = pd.to_datetime('2018-06-01 08:55:10')

time = start
# iterate each sensor interval
# must be sorted by time, and no intervals should overlap
for (i, row) in df.iterrows():
    # go to the next interval when time is after current interval
    while time < row['end']:
        if time >= row['start']:
            results.append([time, 1])
        else:
            results.append([time, 0])
        time += interval

result_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['time', 'active'])
result_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['time'])
print(result_df)
```

Result:

```
                 time  active
0 2018-06-01 08:55:10       1
1 2018-06-01 09:00:10       1
2 2018-06-01 09:05:10       0
3 2018-06-01 09:10:10       0
4 2018-06-01 09:15:10       1
5 2018-06-01 09:20:10       1
```

It should take a few seconds for 15m rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, @klaus! That's a nice way of doing it. Unfortunately my intervals are not disjoint.